# Is it possible to have multiple tools open of the same type on Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm using dual monitors and I was trying to set some tools(ie. Team Explorer) on both monitors while i'm using Visual Studio, is it possible?

Comment: You can have different 'modes' of team explorer open at the same time - like the home page, pending changes, builds, and source control explorer - but you can only have one of each open.

Answer (score 0):

You can undock the tool windows and move them to another screen.

- Double-click the window's title bar.
- Right click the window's title bar, and then click Float.

[image]

Comment: yes but I want to know if it's possible to have 2 or more of the same, like 1 on each screen

Comment: Unless the extension has an explicit support, it is not possible https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/creating-a-multi-instance-tool-window.md